# Magento 2 product list

Tags: magento2, product-list

`/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` is the template responsible for the product list in a category page for example, it loads the products collection and the print it with a classic `foreach ($_productCollection as $_product)`.

Inside the foreach we have:

```
<?php $iterator = 1; ?>
<ol class="products list items product-items">
    <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
        ...
        <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
```

why not a simpler code like this?

```
<ol class="products list items product-items">
    <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item product product-item">
        ...
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: @ Lorenzo As of my observation there is a lot of discussion going on the code like this. But no one has cleared the ambiguity +1 .  ref http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180501/which-is-better-to-include-html-inside-php-code-or-outside-it